# Bootstrap Migration from Alpha 4.2 to 4.6

Tags: migration, alpha, bootstrap-4

I am migrating a project from Bootstrap Alpha 4.2 to 4.6

Some components are missing in the 4.6 Version.

Is there any documentation which components are removed/rewritten/deleted ?

I cannot find any documentation whatsoever on how to migrate my project.

Anything is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no doc for migrating within the alpha versions as instability is expected in any pre-release stage. Read the docs on migrating to Bootstrap 4 to see the latest changes: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/9090/migrating-to-bootstrap-4/28674/bootstrap-4-navbar#t=201707071021514705939

Comment: List of classes that have changed: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/9090/migrating-to-bootstrap-4/28792/bootstrap-3-to-bootstrap-4-css-changes#t=201707071205035782619

Comment: Thanks Zim, that is really useful